# Laravel homestead serve documents from root directory

Tags: homestead

I have to browse to `http://test.local/test/` in order to view `index.php`. Of course I really want to be able to view this script from `http://test.local`. What is wrong with my config?

```
//  .homestead/Homestead.yaml
ip: "192.168.0.2"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
 - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
 - map: ~/Code
   to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
 - map: homestead.app
   to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
 - map: test.local
   #to: /var/www/test
   to: ~/Documents/www/test <-- now pointing to


/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   andy-desktop
192.168.0.2 test.local


$ ls -l /var/www/test/
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x 1 andy andy 31 May 12 14:22 index.php
```

and why are my documents being served from `/test` ?

Comment: Have you tried placing files in /var/www ?

Comment: It's a weird one this. I placed the file one directory up and it served OK i.e. from `http://test.local`. However, it also served the exact same file from `http://localhost` despite the script not even being present in `localhost` root. This led me to believe my local `LAMP` setup was somehow interfering with vagrant. I then remove `Apache` from the machine entirely to confirm this. I move the vagrant files over to `~/Documents/www/test` Now `http://test.local` (vagrant) won't load any scripts from this domain returning `403 Forbidden`?

Comment: Sorry but that's as far as I can help you, you'r current error goes beyond my knowledge. Glad to at least have given you a hand!

Comment: I was on the wrong track entirely. I solved by it by defining public private key pairs RSA and following along with: https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-laravel-homestead

Comment: Nice work! Go aheaed and post this as an answer!